# Match exact closest string with regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string:

```
Test.
<div>
<table style="color:blue;"><tbody><!--START SPACE COMMENTS SUMMARY-->
<tr><td colspan="2">SPACE COMMENTS SUMMARY</td></tr>
<tr><td style="min-width:200px;">Area/Room</td>
<td style="max-width:300px;text-align:left;">Comments</td>
</tr><tr><td style="min-width:200px;">Bathroom</td>
<td style="max-width:300px;text-align:left;">Some comment</td></tr>
<!--END SPACE COMMENTS SUMMARY--></tbody></table>
<div>
<table style="color:blue;"><tbody><!--START SPACE SUMMARY-->
<tr><td colspan="2">SPACE SUMMARY</td></tr><tr>
<td style="min-width:200px;">Space</td>
<td style="max-width:300px;text-align:right;">Installed Price</td></tr>
<tr><td style="min-width:200px;">Bathroom</td>
<td style="max-width:300px;text-align:right;">$2,355.97</td></tr>
<!--END SPACE SUMMARY--></tbody></table>
<br><br><br><div>Some text.</div></div></div>
```

I want to select with regex a table that has comments `<!--START SPACE SUMMARY>` and `<!--END SPACE SUMMARY-->`.

I tried with `@"<table.*?><tbody.*?><!--START SPACE SUMMARY>.*?<!--END SPACE SUMMARY--></tbody></table>"`, but it selects both tables in the string.

EDIT:
My question doesn't have to do precisely with HTML. The same question will stand if I had a string:

```
some text blah blah one some text blah blah two.
```

And I want to select `some text blah blah two` with a pattern `some text.*?two`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Why use a Regex here and not `IndexOf()` or something?

Comment: @Thomas can Regex be inserted in IndexOf()? By the way, I don't need to know if the string exists, but to select the content.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/zM9gU1/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string test = @"Test.
    <div>
    <table style=""color:blue;""><tbody><!--START SPACE COMMENTS SUMMARY-->
    <tr><td colspan=""2"">SPACE COMMENTS SUMMARY</td></tr>
    <tr><td style=""min-width:200px;"">Area/Room</td>
    <td style=""max-width:300px;text-align:left;"">Comments</td>
    </tr><tr><td style=""min-width:200px;"">Bathroom</td>
    <td style=""max-width:300px;text-align:left;"">Some comment</td></tr>
    <!--END SPACE COMMENTS SUMMARY--></tbody></table>
    <div>
    <table style=""color:blue;""><tbody><!--START SPACE SUMMARY-->
    <tr><td colspan=""2"">SPACE SUMMARY</td></tr><tr>
    <td style=""min-width:200px;"">Space</td>
    <td style=""max-width:300px;text-align:right;"">Installed Price</td></tr>
    <tr><td style=""min-width:200px;"">Bathroom</td>
    <td style=""max-width:300px;text-align:right;"">$2,355.97</td></tr>
    <!--END SPACE SUMMARY--></tbody></table>
    <br><br><br><div>Some text.</div></div></div>";

MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(test, @"<table(?!.*<table).*?<!--START SPACE SUMMARY-->.*?<!--END SPACE SUMMARY-->.*?table>", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

The idea is to use `(?!.*<table)` to tell Regex engine the the text within should not contain another table anchor.

Answer (score 1):

Let's focus on a non-HTML problem you have: match the closest window between two delimiters. Use a [**tempered greedy token**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed):

```
(?s)some text(?:(?!some text|two).)*two
    |<-1st->||<----TG Token ------>||
                                    |2nd delimiter
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zM9gU1/1)

For an HTML parsing, use [HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), it will make life easier to everyone who is going to maintain your code.

The `(?s)` turns on DOTALL mode when `.` matches any character including a newline and `(?:(?!some text|two).)*` tempered greedy token will match any character that is not the starting character of `some text` or `two` literal character sequences.

Comment: All right. But to put in context of what I really need - how to get `some maybe more text blah blah two` from string `some more text blah blah one some maybe more text blah blah two`? Using words `some`, `text` and `two`.

Comment: Same way, just the right side can be anything, as we are not interested in it: https://regex101.com/r/pE1qG5/1

Comment: Have you checked the suggested solution? It is selecting all the text.

Comment: Ok, I see, I updated it before closing the window, sorry. The safest way is to use the token on the right side, too: [`some(?:(?!some|two|text).)*text(?:(?!some|two|text).)*two`](https://regex101.com/r/pE1qG5/2).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<table.*?><tbody.*?><!--START (SPACE SUMMARY)>.*?<!--END \1--><\/tbody><\/table>
```

It should be done with non-greedy, but I try to use variable `\1` here to repeat group 1 value. And also escape the `/` to `\/`. Maybe that's the problem source.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not returning any match.